# C# Override method from Collection<T>

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I would like to notify to the user each time that the program add a new Item in a List.

I did this:

```
public class ListDemo<T> : Collection<T>
{
    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("YOU HAVE INSERTED AN ITEM");
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }
}
```

I could inherit *ListDemo* from the interface **IList**, but I don't want to implement all the methods of this interface... So I inherited from **Collection**

Now I have two questions about my code:

**1º**  Do I have to notify to the user with an event? Or my code is good?

**2º**  How Can I call to the override method? Like an Interface?

```
         // IT WORKS!
         List<int> _list = new ListDemo<int>();
        _list.Insert(0,2);
        Console.WriteLine(_list[0]);
```

This code works, and it is very strange for me, because when you call to an interface you must use this way:

```
        Collection<int> _list = new ListDemo<int>();
```

**3º** Why if the override method is **InsertItem**, then when I call to the method from my instance this is simply **Insert**.

Comment: Oh dear... I think you have a lot of reading in front of you, regarding many different topics (inheritance, design patterns, user interaction ...). I vote to close this question as to broad because you officially ask three questions here, so a focused answer will not be a single answer but instead a multi-part text of different answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `InsertItem` is a *virtual* method of `Collection<T>`:

```
protected virtual void InsertItem(
    int index,
    T item
)
```

Please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132412(v=vs.110).aspx). So when a type inherits a `Collection<T>` then it can override this method and when `InsertItem` is called the overriden one it would be called.

On the other hand `List<T>` doesn't not inherits `Collection<T>` so there isn't any method called `InsertItem`.

That being said, defining you object as below:

```
var listDemo = new ListDemo<int>();
listDemo.InsertItem(0,2);
```

you would achieve that you want, because now the type of listDemo inherits from `Collection<int>` and you have overriden this method.

Comment: Thanks very much! I understood very good with your example!!,,, @grek40 If Christos was able to answer my questions, why close this post...

Comment: @JoseAviles You are welcome ! I am glad that I helped :)

Comment: @JoseAviles The fact that someone was able to give you the information you needed is somewhat unrelated to whether the question was fully answered. I think you asked more than what you actually wanted to know, so you are now satisfied without a full answer. The answer is good, but it doesn't address everything you originally asked for.

Answer (score 2):

If you implementation does what you want, there is no problem. That being said, there is already a predefined type `ObservableCollection<T>`, which is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx), which does exactly what you want, namely providing a mechanism for notifications if the content of the collections changes.